# Help with installing Hope in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am quiet new to ubuntu OS. It would be of great help if someone could suggest and explain the commands in installing Hope software.The manual provides the following steps:

I.  To install hope, follow the procedures described below.

```
1. To install hope, make a bin directory under your home
   directory. Suppose that the home directory is ~cad and
   the source code of hope is under the directory
   ~cad/etg/hope.

2. Go to the directory hope.
   "cd ~cad/etg/hope".

3. To compile hope, type "make".
   An execution file "hope" will be created.

4. Copy or symbolically link hope to the directory ~cad/bin using
   "cp hope ~cad/bin" or
   "ln -s hope ~cad/bin/hope".
```

II. Before using hope, each user should set the following
    two environment variables as described below.

```
1. Set  your path (or PATH) environment variable to include
   ~cad/bin in your search path. This variable, in general,
   can be found in your ".cshrc" file. For example, the line

   set path = ( .... ~cad/bin)

   includes ~cad/bin to your search path.

2. Set the HOPE_MAN environment variable to indicate the
   directory hope, where the on-line manual of hope is
   located, using the setenv command as shown below.

   "setenv HOPE_MAN ~cad/etg/hope"

   If you use hope frequently, add the above command to your
   ".cshrc" file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual should also tell what to put in the `~cad/etg/hope` directory.

All the listed commands should be typed at the Terminal prompt. Hold CTRL and ALT keys, then press T - that will open a Terminal.
Each command needs a press on ENTER at the end, this to get it executed.

Note that `~cad` in the description above may be directly replaced by `$USER` - and the instructions will work directly (with that change).

So `"cd ~cad/etg/hope"`  becomes `cd $USER/etg/hope`

Create the hope directory, if it doesn't exist:
`mkdir -p $USER/etg/hope`

Create the bin directory, if it doesn't exist:
`mkdir -p $USER/bin`

This more complex command will tell **which file** that contains "PATH" (the portion before ':' is the name).
`cd; grep PATH .* 2>&1 | grep -vE 'dir|denied'`

You need to edit that file and append `:$USER/bin` to the end of the line that contains `PATH=`

To edit the file, type
`nano name_of_the_file`

With nano running; the bottom of the screen will contain keys to press to access functions in `nano` - i.e. saving the file, and exiting nano.
Note that `^` denotes holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and pressing the listed key.

If the 'complex command' above doesn't print anything, then there is NO file that contains PATH; then type:
`echo >>.bashrc 'set PATH=$PATH:$USER/bin'`
*note the use of `'`-quotes, this is an important difference here.*

Then:
`setenv HOPE_MAN $USER/etg/hope`
... add it to the end of the same file (on a new line) as where you put PATH e.g. with
`nano .bashrc`
... if that is where PATH ended up.